# Should I Refrain From Editing My Answer If Someone Plagiarized It

Tags: discussion, flags, plagiarism

If I post an answer and someone subsequently posts the same answer, after I flag, should I refrain from editing my original answer until the flag is reviewed?

I would think keeping my original post time would make the flag evaluation more straight-forward and obvious.

Comment: You can link to a particular revision of the post in the flag message.

Comment: Though if the post has not yet been edited there is nothing to copy the link from AFAIK. For this question it is `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/272366/1`

Comment: I guess I could've also added in the question whether or not moderators reviewing flags are able (and typically) see revisions of answers in this kind of situation.

Comment: I actually had a case like this where, because of the grace period on repeated edits, the plagiarized text ended up being somewhere between my revision 1 and my revision 2. (Also, the copier missed all the formatting, and left off the last 3 letters, so it wouldn't have been _identical_ anyway.) The moderator was apparently still able to tell what happened and deleted the copy accordingly… but if you're worried about something like this, maybe mention it in the flag comment?

Comment: @abarnert CC-BY-SA 3.0, the license for content on this site, states: "copy, remix, transform (...) in any form (...) build upon the material". So it doesn't matter if parts are left off or not properly formatted to be plagiarized content that must be removed or altered.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If someone outright plagiarized your answer, and they were flagged for it, we'll usually look back through an both answers' histories to verify this. We try to figure out why someone flagged an answer like that if the two don't exactly match at a first glance.

I should caution that just because someone used a code snippet that might have existed within your answer, that doesn't completely indicate that it was plagiarized from your answer. We have a little higher bar for this, and I tend to look for copied wording over similar code before I decide if something has been plagiarized or not. We might decline for reasons like that, but usually we look to see what the states were of the answers at the time the alleged plagiarism took place.

If you do want to call this out, and know that you'll be editing your answer, you can just state in your flag that the copying took place from your original version of the answer (we don't need a link to figure out where to go for that). We can do the rest.

Comment: "We have a little higher bar for this" might not be entirely true. The license that sits on top of every content provided by users on this page requires attribution. On a personal side, when I am searching for an answer, reading the same thing twice is very annoying and I prefer answers with notes like "extending on @foobar answer".

Comment: Or, heck, using comments like you just did.

Comment: I've had an answer where the user not just _copied_ mine, but also posted a comment to the OP pointing out their answer as the solution. Amazingly the _cheat_ worked and the OP chose their answer.

Comment: Ah, and I ended up flagging just the comment. :/

Comment: @kaiser - What I mean by that is that sometimes multiple people will arrive at the same solution in code, but it is extremely unlikely that those people will independently write the same sentence. Therefore, it is a lot easier to demonstrate that wording is copied vs. code. Sometimes there only is one viable way to solve something in code, but there is always a different way to word an explanation about it. This has little to do with license, but about the kind of proof we need that something was indeed copied from another user or source.